# Assign a string literal to a char*

Tags: c#, unsafe

just messing around with the unsafe side of c#

```
unsafe {
    char* m = stackalloc char[3+1];
    m[0] = 'A';
    m[1] = 'B';
    m[2] = 'C';
    m[3] = '\0';
    for (char* c = m; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        Console.WriteLine(*c);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Is it possible to assign a `string` literal to a `char` pointer just like in C or do I have to do it as in the above snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
string m = "abc";
unsafe 
{
    fixed (char* pm = m)
    {               

    }
}
```

`fixed`  sets a pointer to a managed variable and "pins" that variable so the GC won't clean it up.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f58wzh21(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yup, and it allows you to modify the string on the fly. Obviously, it's a very bad idea to do this. Especially for interned strings.

Comment: Therefore its called "unsafe".